# Insert data with ManyToMany in symfony 4

Tags: symfony4

I have a ManyToMany relationship between two entities Project and User, I create a project with the method PostACtion () and it works but there is not an insertion in the associative table "project_user",
my problem is at the level of the methodPOST when I create a project must retrieve the two id (id project and iduser) so that I can insert in the associative table,
that's my solution I do not know if my idea is correct or not

**projectController**

```
 /**
 * Create a new project.
 *
 * @param Request $request
 * @param Validator $validator
 * @return ApiCreatedResponse
 *
 * @SWG\Parameter(name="project", in="body", @Model(type=ProjectType::class))
 * @SWG\Response(response=201, description="Project Created", @Model(type=Project::class))
 *
 * @Rest\Post("projects")
 */



public function postAction(Request $request, Validator $validator)
{
    $data = $request->request->all();

    /** @var Project $project */
    $project = $validator->validateForm(ProjectType::class, $data)->getData();


    $this->projectManager->saveProject($project);



    return new ApiCreatedResponse(['project' => $project]);

}
```

**projectphp**

```
 private $creator;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->creator = new ArrayCollection();
}
 public function getCreator(): Collection
{
    return $this->creator;
} ....
```

**userphp**

```
 private $projects;

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->projects = new ArrayCollection();
}
```

**projectType**

```
   /**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('url', TextType::class)
        ->add('title')
        ->add('type', TextType::class)
        ->add('urlSsh');
      //  ->add('creator', CollectionType::class);

}
```

Comment: You need to show more of your entity classes (Project and User), specifically your definitions of the `projects` and `users` parameters and the setter functions for each. I suspect your problem has to do with properly assigning the owning and inverse sides of your ManyToMany relationship and then setting up your setters appropriately from there.